# Why bash time is more precise then GNU time?

Tags: bash, time, gnu

The buitin bash command `time` gives milisecond precision of execution and GNU `time` (usually /usr/bin/time) gives centisecond precision. The `times(2)` syscall gives times in clocks, and 100 clocks = 1 second (usually), so the precision is like GNU `time`. So the question is what is bash `time` using so that it's more precise?

Comment: Hmmm... they both give milliseconds on my system... (FC16)

Comment: Strange. What gives you printf("%d\n", sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)); should be 100 as I stated above. Someone have similar observations to mine: http://www.dirac.org/linux/time/ but still no explanation.

Comment: yes, in effect it gives 100...

Comment: Then I have no idea why's that. GNU time is supposed to use times syscall which uses sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) to convert to seconds.

Comment: FWIW When you say "bash `time`", I assume you mean BSD `time` as that uses `getrusage`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some hardcore bash code examining I found out that bash `time` uses `getrusage()` and GNU `time` uses `times()`. `getrusage()` is far more precise because of microsecond resolution.