# Increase %e precision with /usr/bin/time shell command

Tags: shell, scripting, time

When I run the time command in shell `time ./myapp` I get an output like the following:

```
real    0m0.668s
user    0m0.112s
sys     0m0.028s
```

However,when I run the command `\time -f %e ./myapp` I lose precision and I get:

```
2.01s
```

If I use the `%E` command I also lose precision in the same way. How do I change it to have more precision again, but still only have the seconds being outputted?

I based my research in this [Linux / Unix Command: time](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm)  and on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27920/why-bash-time-is-more-precise-then-gnu-time)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm assuming you understand that both these commands are calling a different version of time, right?

#### bash's built-in version

```
% time
```

#### GNU time aka. /usr/bin/time

```
% \time
```

The built-in `time` command to `bash` can be read up on here:

```
% help time
time: time [-p] PIPELINE
    Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time,
    and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates.
    The return status is the return status of PIPELINE.  The `-p' option
    prints the timing summary in a slightly different format.  This uses
    the value of the TIMEFORMAT variable as the output format.
```

The GNU `time`, `/usr/bin/time`, is usually more useful than the built-in.

As to your precision problem it's covered here in this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/linse/3737870), specifically:

#### Why is bash time more precise then GNU time?

> The builtin bash command time gives milisecond precision of execution,
>   and GNU time (usually /usr/bin/time) gives centisecond precision. The
>   times(2) syscall gives times in clocks, and 100 clocks = 1 second
>   (usually), so the precision is like GNU time. What is bash time using
>   so that it is more precise?
>
> Bash time internally uses getrusage() and GNU time uses times().
>   getrusage() is far more precise because of microsecond resolution.

You can see the centiseconds with the following example (*see 5th line of output*):

```
% /usr/bin/time -v sleep .22222
    Command being timed: "sleep .22222"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.22
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1968
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 153
    Voluntary context switches: 2
    Involuntary context switches: 1
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

More resolution can be had using bash's `time` command like so & you can control the resolution:

```
# 3 places 
% TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time ( sleep .22222 )
0.224
```

From the [Bash manual on variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

```
TIMEFORMAT
The value of this parameter is used as a format string specifying how the timing information for pipelines prefixed with the time reserved word should be displayed. The ‘%’ character introduces an escape sequence that is expanded to a time value or other information. The escape sequences and their meanings are as follows; the braces denote optional portions.

%%
A literal ‘%’.

%[p][l]R
The elapsed time in seconds.

%[p][l]U
The number of CPU seconds spent in user mode.

%[p][l]S
The number of CPU seconds spent in system mode.

%P
The CPU percentage, computed as (%U + %S) / %R.

The optional p is a digit specifying the precision, the number of fractional digits after a decimal point. A value of 0 causes no decimal point or fraction to be output. At most three places after the decimal point may be specified; values of p greater than 3 are changed to 3. If p is not specified, the value 3 is used.

The optional l specifies a longer format, including minutes, of the form MMmSS.FFs. The value of p determines whether or not the fraction is included.

If this variable is not set, Bash acts as if it had the value

$'\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys\t%3lS'
If the value is null, no timing information is displayed. A trailing newline is added when the format string is displayed.
```

Comment: yes I already knew all of that. So I can conclude that what I want is impossible ? Is there a way to use the bash time version and only get the real secs time with 3 digits?

Comment: See my update, you can control bash's time command using the variable TIMEFORMAT. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yah, that's it, thanks! I am wondering though, how do I append that to a file? I am trying to use % TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time ( sleep .22222 ) >> bla.txt but it's not working :S Anyway, selected. I wish I could give you karma++, but I don't have 15 karma -.-'

Comment: TIMEFORMAT='%3R'; time ( sleep .22222 ) 2>>myFile.txt GOt it !

Comment: Long time user of both and didn't know about `TIMEFORMAT`, I always used sed to extract real time. Thanks! The "because of microsecond resolution." statement put my hopes up that `TIMEFORMAT=%6R` would work but it seems that the precision digit may only be 0-3.