# Automatic transformation of newlines in shell variable assignment

Tags: shell, newlines, bc

This came out of one of my comments to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117280/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-bash-shell-not-warning-you-of-arithmetic-overflow) regarding the use of `bc` in shell scripting.  `bc` puts line breaks in large numbers, e.g.:

```
> num=$(echo 6^6^3 | bc)
> echo $num
12041208676482351082020900568572834033367326934574532243581212211450\ 20555710636789704085475234591191603986789604949502079328192358826561\ 895781636115334656050057189523456
```

But notice they aren't really line breaks in the variable -- or at least there are not if it is used unquoted.  For example, in fooling around with more pipe in the assignment, e.g.:

```
num=$(echo 6^6^3 | bc | perl -pne 's/\\\n//g')
```

I realized that while there really is an `\n` in the `bc` output, checking `echo $num > tmp.txt` with `hexdump` shows the `\n` (ASCII 10) has definitely become a space (ASCII 32) in the variable assignment.

Or at least, in the output of unquoted `$num >`. **Why is that?**

As fedorqui points out, if you use quotes: `echo "$num"`, you get newlines again.  This is evident by examining the difference between `echo $num > tmp.1` and `echo "$num" > tmp.2` with hexdump; the former contains `\` (backslash space) whereas the later contains `\\n` (backslash newline).

Comment: If you quote when `echo`ing, it shows new lines but with trailing slash: `echo "$num"`.

Comment: If find `cat -A` a good intermediate for looking at this kind of thing before going to `hexdump` or the like. Eg `echo 6^6^3 | bc | cat -A`.

Comment: @fedorqui : Interesting, since that seems to be a further interpolation -- I've added a last paragraph about this.

Comment: In general, quoting while `echo`ing is important to keep the original format. Hence, you have to trust the quoted `echo` when working with some text.

Comment: @fedorqui : Right, my "last paragraph" was actually a little confused on that -- of course it isn't really a "further interpolation".  Did not know about this aspect of quotes vs. non-quotes, tho.  Do you know of anywhere that stipulates all the transformations that occur?

Comment: OK I found a reference. See [Shell command language - 2.2.3 Double-Quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) --> "Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters backquote, <dollar-sign>, and <backslash>".

Comment: @fedorqui : Okay, but why would backslash-newline be transformed to backslash-space when **unquoted**?  2.2.1 from there actually states that *"A <backslash> that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a <newline>. If a <newline> follows the <backslash>, the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. The <backslash> and <newline> shall be removed...the escaped <newline> is removed entirely"* but clearly that is not at all what is happening.  The escaped newline is being replaced by an "escaped" space character.

Comment: @Graeme, `sed -n l` is better that `cat -A` as it's non-ambiguous (and is standard/portable). With cat -A, if you see `^M`, you don't know if it's a CR character or the two characters `^` and `M` or `^` followed by a _meta_ character.

Comment: @Stephane, good tip, thanks. Thought you would have the definitive answer for this...

Comment: You're quoting a section about shell parsing, that's different from what the shell does upon variable expansion (the split+glob operator)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : Okay, so parsing of input vs. expansion of output? In that case I would still expect it to apply when the variable *is assigned to*. Is the "split+glob" operator real or just something you have used for explication?  I can't find any reference to that anywhere else (see my answer here).

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22565+split%2Bglob, or more specifically [this answer to _Why do I need to quote variable for if, but not for echo?_](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65624/why-do-i-need-to-quote-variable-for-if-but-not-for-echo/65633#65633) (of which your question is almost a duplicate)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : I know -- I refer to one of those in my answer here.  What I meant was, is that *your* moniker for the operation?  Evidently so, which is fine by me, I just wanted to make sure there is no point looking for other explications of it (by name) in shell docs, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` puts a space between each two arguments. The shell considers the newline in `$num` just a word separator (just like space).

```
lines="a
b
c"
set -x
echo $lines   # several arguments to echo
echo "$lines" # one argument to echo
```

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117497/25985) (by the OP himself) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm going to give you the tick but for posterity refer to [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117497/25985) which provides some more detail for (other) people who are caught off guard by this.

Answer (score 7):

No idea why its there, but here's how to disable it with the GNU implementation of `bc`:

```
echo '6^6^3' | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc
```

> BC_LINE_LENGTH
>
> This  should  be  an integer specifying the number of characters in an output line for numbers. This includes the backslash and newline characters for long numbers.  As an
>                 extension, the value of zero disables the multi-line feature.  Any other value of this variable that is less than 3 sets the line length to 70.

#### Update:

I was confused about this question, I thought it was about the origins of the multi-line feature, it does seem like an odd one. Anyway the real answer is that if you do not quote the variable, the shell will do **word splitting** on it before this is passed to `echo`. **Word splitting** is the process where an expansion is split into 'words' depending on the contents of `IFS`, these 'words' then become different arguments. In the question example, this creates two arguments to echo, which `echo` then separates with a space (I knew this before Stephane commented, honest...).

To prevent this happening, just double quote the variable:

```
num=$(echo '6^6^3' | bc)
echo "$num"
```

Sometimes this is actually useful as a way to remove IFS characters from a variable (although `printf %s` is safer for arbitrary strings). Eg (in `bash`):

```
$ var=$'spaces:    newlines:\n\n\ntabs:\t\t\t end'

$ echo "$var"
spaces:    newlines:


tabs:            end
$ newvar="$(printf '%s ' $var)"
$ echo "$newvar"
spaces: newlines: tabs: end
```

Comment: +1 for the tip about `bc`!

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr` to delete the line continuations and the newlines:

```
$ num=$(echo 6^6^3 | bc)
$ echo "$num"
12041208676482351082020900568572834033367326934574532243581212211450\
20555710636789704085475234591191603986789604949502079328192358826561\
895781636115334656050057189523456
$ num=$(echo "$num" | tr -d '\n\\')
$ echo "$num"
12041208676482351082020900568572834033367326934574532243581212211450205557106367897040854752345911916039867896049495020793281923588265618957816361153346560500571895 23456
```

Comment: I'm actually not looking for a way to remove the newlines (there are no doubt dozens).  I'm looking for an explanation as to how/why a newline ends up interpreted as a space.

Comment: @goldilocks, it's not interpreted as a space, it's just that you're using the split+glob operator by leaving your variables unquoted (and echo outputs its arguments separated by a space).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the bc man page, under expressions, it does explain the limit.

> Since numbers are  of arbitrary  precision,  some numbers may not be
>   printable on a single output line. These long numbers will be split
>   across lines using the "\" as the  last  character on a line.  The
>   maximum number of characters printed per line is 70.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Stephane Chazelas's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117479/automatic-transformation-of-newlines-in-shell-variable-assignment/117482#comment183327_117482), the issue not exactly that the space is interpreted as a newline.  He's explained this [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65633/25985) in relation to a  (conceptual) "split+glob" operator, and although I don't totally follow the semantics of that, here's what's happening:

- The unquoted variable is split *on whitespace* by the shell and these are passed as arguments to `echo`.  The splitting removes the whitespace. This may be a bit confusing since "backslash-newline" seems like an escape sequence, but it is NOT equivalent to `x=\\\n`, it's is equivalent to `x=$'\\\012'`, `\012` being octal for an actual newline -- as opposed to the escape sequence `\\n`, which results in the string containing a literal "\n" (backslash-n), which would not be split.
- `echo` then outputs its arguments separated by a space.

To reiterate:

```
str1=hello\\nworld
str2=$'hello\012world'
```

The shell will not split the first one unquoted since it doesn't actually contain any whitespace -- it contains the escape sequence `\n`, whereas in the second case it will be split unquoted on the actual newline character (which is whitespace).

Comment: By 'split-glob' he means word splitting followed by glob (or 'pathname') expansion (I know this much). Also splits are on whatever `IFS` is, so it could be just newlines or just spaces.

Comment: @Graeme : Cheers.  I think of "the glob operator" as referring specifically to `*` when really it's one of a number of *globbing* operators.   So my own misnomer.

Comment: About splitting and globbing, try reading [Expansion of a shell variable and effect of glob and split on it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/expansion-of-a-shell-variable-and-effect-of-glob-and-split-on-it/109074#109074) and following the links in that answer.