# Multiplying numbers from each line in file is giving minus value

Tags: bash, files, arithmetic

```
#!/bin/bash

sed  's/[^0-9 ]*//g'  $1 | tr " " "\n" > outfile.txt

sed '/^\s*$/d' outfile.txt > outfile1.txt


if [ $2 == "-s" ] || [ $2 == "-si" ] || [ $2 == "-is" ]
then
sum=0;
while read num;
do ((sum += num));
done < outfile1.txt;
echo "SUMA= $sum"
fi

if [ $2 == "-i" ] || [ $2 == "-si" ] || [ $2 == "-is" ]
then
ilo=1;
while read num1;
do((ilo = num1 * ilo));
echo $num1
done < outfile1.txt;
echo "ILOCZYN= $ilo"
fi
```

this is my script and this is 1st argument file

```
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 3 4 5 4 3 
2 2 2 2 22 3 34 4 4 5 5 5 d 
3 43 54 5 3
```

this is what im getting from the script when i want to get an multiply of all the numbers and sum of them

```
s17545@msh:~$ ./skrypt12.sh logfile.txt -si
SUMA= 241
1
.
. all of the numbers in outfile1.txt 
.
3
ILOCZYN= -2888071394797551616
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly related: [What is the rationale for the bash shell not warning you of arithmetic overflow etc.?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117280/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-bash-shell-not-warning-you-of-arithmetic-overflow)

Comment: So is there any walkabout or i am just fine to accept my destiny of limits :D?

Comment: In theory, you could write an *arbitrary precision arithmetic package* for bash, but unless you take particular fun out of such a task, it is much easier to use instead one of those many programming languages which already come with such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117280/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-bash-shell-not-warning-you-of-arithmetic-overflow) [linked by @steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447416/multiplying-numbers-from-each-line-in-file-is-giving-minus-value#comment811633_447416) explains, arithmetic overflow is a fact of life in Bash. You could instead:

- use a language which supports arbitrary-size numbers out of the box such as (I believe) Haskell, Lisp or Scheme,
- use a language which will throw an exception at arithmetic overflow, such as Java or Rust,
- check whether the product has decreased after each operation (since all your numbers are positive), or
- rethink your approach so that you don't need to multiply all the numbers in one go (which of course isn't always possible).

Comment: There's also `dc` e.g. `sed -z 's/[^0-9][^0-9]*/*/2g' "$1" | dc -f - -ep`

Comment: Python does bignums, and is likely already installed on more systems than the languages you name. Java does _not_ throw for integer (primitive) overflow; it wraps-around. (For FP it uses IEEE which doesn't overflow at all but has +-Infinity values. For BigInteger, it does throw ArithmeticException or OutOfMemory, but only for humongous values.)