# Multiply digits within a number with each other

Tags: bash

I have list of numbers, and I want to multiply the digits within each number with each other; e.g. for the number 1234 it is 1 X 2 X 3 X 4 = 24

E.g. the following input

```
7675342567
098765342567
1234567890
0987654
234567
8765678
98
0999
09876543
345678
876543
87654
```

needs the following result:

```
7408800
0
0
0
5040
564480
72
0
0
20160
20160
6720
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Sorry but this is not a scripting service. If you do not know any shell scripting, you'd start learning.

Comment: @andcoz i don't like programming and it is not my hobby, I have problem and I need help what is wrong with that?

Comment: Sydney: The problem is that this site teaches people programming. If you don't care about the "how", pay someone to solve the problem for you.

Comment: "what is wrong with that?" is a complex question, please read this: [How do you feel about “GIVE ME TEH CODEZ” questions?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/how-do-you-feel-about-give-me-teh-codez-questions)

Comment: *[Homework: policy proposal](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344)*

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can do it this way:

```
<file sed 's/./&*/g;s/*$//' | bc

7408800
0
0
0
5040
564480
72
0
0
20160
20160
6720
```

With GNU `sed`, that can be simplified as:

```
<file sed 's/./*&/2g' | bc
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly within bash, assuming you don't [overflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117280/117549) beyond 9 quintillion and change (9,223,372,036,854,775,807),

```
while IFS= read -r 
do 
  res=1
  for((i=0;i<${#REPLY};i++))
  do 
    res=$((res * ${REPLY:i:1}))
  done
  echo "$res"
done < input > output
```