# Printing milliseconds with GNU time

Tags: time, benchmark

I am using GNU time for benchmarking and would like to measure real, user and sys time to the nearest millisecond. That is, I want to measure seconds to 3 decimal places, not the default 2. Does GNU time offer such an option?

Comment: Are you using the built-in/keyword time or the external time?

Comment: I'm using the build-in time, I believe. It is /usr/bin/time.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I am using GNU time. I am executing the command from a Node.js Child Process, which itself is running inside a Docker container. The default behaviour is to print:

%Uuser %Ssystem %Eelapsed %PCPU (%Xtext+%Ddata %Mmax)k
           %Iinputs+%Ooutputs (%Fmajor+%Rminor)pagefaults %Wswaps

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70653/increase-e-precision-with-usr-bin-time-shell-command

Comment: Good find. Read that earlier but I wasn't able to get much from it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you could, the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) does list a number of formatting options, but there's no provision for setting the accuracy. For example, `%e`, `%S` and `%U` seem to always give the output with two decimal places.

On the other hand, Bash's builtin `time` does support setting the number of digits after the decimal point, up to 3, so you might be able to use it to get what you wanted. The `TIMEFORMAT` environment variable controls the output format:

```
$ TIMEFORMAT='real: %3R user: %3U sys: %3S cpu: %P' bash -c 'time sleep 1.233'
real: 1.234 user: 0.000 sys: 0.000 cpu: 0.00
```

Or just without setting `TIMEFORMAT`, since the default output also shows three digits. It does separate minutes though:

```
$ bash -c 'time sleep 1.233'

real    0m1.234s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The [`getrusage()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) gives the times as `struct timeval`, so up to microseconds, so I suppose you could make your own implementation of `time` to get more accuracy. A whole another thing is how accurate the numbers actually are.

Comment: Thanks! I was calling time from a Node.js child_process instance which enforced use of GNU time for some reason or another. I was finally able to enforce bash time using `/bin/bash -c "time <my command>"`. Shame about GNU time not allowing formatting, though.

Comment: @JacobBaird, oh, right, the default format already shows three digits, so it's not even necessary to modify it. Setting `TIMEFORMAT` to `%3R %3U %3S` might make the output easier to parse, since there would be less to parse and you'd get raw seconds instead of seconds + minutes.